# How can I keep the initial value of fit-content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to **keep the initial value** of a CSS property when it is set to `fit-content` for example? (or anything that adjusts to the content)

For illustration:

```
.example{
    width: 100px;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

I want the height to be only **set once in the beginning** to fit all the content, but then it should **not adjust when child elements change** (i want it to behave like a constant pixel/percent value):

```
.example{
    width: 100px;
    height: getInitialValue(fit-content); 
    /* height should be a constant value and not change by itself */
}
```

---

I know that it is possible to **implement this behaviour with Javascript** and I could also do that, but it would be much cleaner to do it in pure CSS.

Thank you for your help and suggestions in advance!

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alright, I will implement it with javascript.